# Best way in javascript to repeatedly repeat a function?

Tags: javascript, repeat

I'm doing some visualisation of a 'network evolution model' like thing.
The basic algorithm is:

- some init operations
- 100 evolution steps
- some operations
- 100 evolution steps
- some other operations
- 100 evolution steps
- begin from first step (i.e. the init ops)

So basically, I have to repeat the 100 evolution steps 3 times with unique operations to be done in between, before it all starts again from the beginning.

My current code is somewhat structured like this:

```
var timer;
var counter;
function bigFunction() {

    function hundredSteps() {

        // code for single step

        timer = setTimeout(hundredSteps(), 10);
        counter++;
        stage++;

        if (counter >= 100) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            counter = 0;
            nextStage(stage);
        }
    }

    function nextStage(stage) {

        if (stage == 1) {
            // 1st step code, some init operations
            timer = setTimeout(hundredSteps(), 10);
        }

        if (stage == 2) {
            // 2nd step code, some operations
            timer = setTimeout(hundredSteps(), 10);
        }

        if (stage == 3) {
            // 3rd step code, some other operations
            stage = 0;
            timer = setTimeout(hundredSteps(), 10);
        }
    }

    var stage = 1;
    counter = 0;
    nextStage(stage);
}
```

So I wanted to ask: Is this a 'proper' way to code what I want to achieve? Or would one usually do it differently?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wish to delay each step by 10 ms?

Comment: You are passing to setTimeout the result of hundred steps, I.e. nothing,  instead of the function itself. You're also calling things in a recursive "that's going to explode" kind of way atm.

Comment: inside of hundredSteps() you increment stage, but I think you should probably increment it inside of the if-statement for readability reasons... aside from that, you have basically implemented a state-machine (which is not necessarily a bad thing) but I would be wary of making it a habit

Comment: @JackFrankland Yes, without the delay, the browser hung up, so the delay is needed to ensure that everything works, I think.

Comment: @user3572842: The problem with using `setTimeout` when `hundredSteps` increments `stage` is that `hundredSteps` and `stage` can go out of sync. `setTimeout` makes the code asynchronous, meaning while you wait 10 milliseconds the code will move on quite  alot with that time frame. You need to manage `stage` outside `hundredSteps` to prevent that issue. [**MBottens's answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23293512/448144) looks like it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use set time out, you need to put the function in but not call it. Like so:

```
setTimeout(hundredSteps, 10)
```

or

```
setTimeout(function() {
  hundredSteps()
}, 10)
```

I would clean it all up a bit, for example. In your question you have stage being incremented with counter, when it should be incremented in the next step function. You also have a variable to keep track of the timer, when it isn't completely necessary.

Here is a fiddle of a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Czr8T/1/

```
var counter = 0,
    stage = 1

var hundredSteps = function() {
    counter++

    //Your code here            

    if (counter >= 100) {
        counter = 0
        nextStage()
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(hundredSteps, 10)
    }
}

var nextStage = function() {
    switch (stage) {
        case 1:
            //Your code here
            console.log("Stage one activated")
            break

        case 2:
            //Your code here
            console.log("Stage two activated")
            break

        case 3:
            //Your code here
            stage = 0
            console.log("Stage three activated")
            break
    }

    stage++
    window.setTimeout(hundredSteps, 10)
}

nextStage()
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: +1: This looks like the `setTimeout` might not be causing `stage` and `hundredSteps` to go out of sync as `stage` is incremented within the `nextStage` function. The only thing I'd change is to not call `hundredSteps` outside the switch as it will then also call it when stage is `<0 && >3`.

Comment: it should never go <0 or > 3, case 3 will reset it to 0

Comment: @MBottens: `stage` is in global scope (or in the case of OPs updated code in the scope of `bigFunction`) So any code anywhere within the scope of `bigFunction` or in your code example, the global scope, can change it to any value at any time causing the code to break.

Comment: Ah, I see. Good catch :) I'm just not a big fan of typing the same line multiple times, but maybe a good if statement around the timeout could fix that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, MBottens and François Wahl!

Comment: @user3572842 I made a class out of this, for my own practice, feel free to work on it as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Czr8T/10/